# finding the element in a list closest to the mean of elements in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, mean

This is my array `a= [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]` .
The mean value of a is 155 (i calculated using `sum(a)/len(a)`) but i have to store 100 in a variable instead of 155.

Is there any easy way to solve this problem.

Comment: The way you calculated the mean tells me you are working with lists, and not numpy array. Is that correct? Do you want the solution using numpy?

Comment: yes i was working with numpy array ,sure want a answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to go with pure python, I would write a function like this:

```
from typing import List
numb_list = [1, 4, 10, 20, 55, 102, 77, 89]


def find_closest_to_mean(num_list: List[int])->int:
    mean = sum(numb_list)/len(num_list)
    distance_list = [abs(mean - num) for num in numb_list]
    return num_list[distance_list.index(min(distance_list))]


print(find_closest_to_mean(numb_list))
```

[Out]

```
mean = 44.75
closest number = 55
```

here I create a function called `find_closest_to_mean` that expects a `num_list` argument that is a list of integers. It then first calculates the mean of the list, creates a `distance_list` in which each element corresponds to the distance of the `num_list` in that position with the mean (as an absolute value). lastly it returns an integer from the num_list that has the least distance to the mean.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to find the the index of the value closest to the mean by computing the absolute difference to the mean:

```
a = np.array([5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500])

out = a[np.argmin(np.abs(a-a.mean()))]
```

output: `100`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it pure python, you can use a custom key for `sorted` to find the lowest difference element:

```py
a= [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]
a_mean = sum(a)/len(a)
out = sorted(a, key=lambda val:abs(val-a_mean))[0]
# 100
```

Comment: Use `min`, not `sorted`.